# How to set artifact path for folders using wildcards

Tags: teamcity, wildcard

I want to get `Grinder` test reports as `TeamCity` artifact. There could be different number of report folders:  `grinderReport_0`, `grinderReport_1`, ...`grinderReport_N` and I want to locate all of them in `Reports` folder.

I use `Performance_testing/GrinderAnalyzer.V2.b19/grinderReport_* => Reports`, but this not works as I get `[Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path 'Performance_testing/GrinderAnalyzer.V2.b19/grinderReport_*' not found`. With `Performance_testing/GrinderAnalyzer.V2.b19/grinderReport_0 => Reports` I can get files from first report, but just files- not a separate folder with those files.

So how to use wildcards to match all `N` number of `grinderReport` folders and put all of them into `Reports`?

Answer (score 0):

If the reports are generated in this directory after the build, "Performance_testing/GrinderAnalyzer.V2.b19", try using the following in the artifacts path

**/Performance_testing/GrinderAnalyzer.V2.b19/grinderReport* => Reports

Comment: Yes, path seem to be correct, but again I got `[Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path '**/Performance_testing/GrinderAnalyzer.V2.b19/grinderReport*' not found`

Comment: Are you able to provide more logging info from the Teamcity Logs? The Build agent work directory and logging on when & where these reports are generated?